# Convert Mail enabled public folders to a shared mailbox - O365

Tags: powershell, outlook, office365

Is there a way convert a mail enabled public folder on cloud to a shared mailbox and transfer the email on the public folder to the shared mailbox?
I am hoping to accomplish this without a third party tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, in Office365 they are two **different** object types, you cannot just convert them (without manually). There is also no straight-forward powershell CMDLets for that.

What you have to do is to create a new shared mailbox, gain full access to it, Export public folder to .pst and then import it to the shared mailbox.

Comment: Is there a way to transfer the email address on the public folder to the shared mailbox or the shared mailbox will have to bear the new name that will be assigned when creating it.?

Comment: You can later change the shared mailbox address.